# Flex DateField and MySQL default date value 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, null, datefield

I created a service and callResponder (Via Generate Service Call and Generate Form in Flash Builder 4) that query a MySQL database for a name and a birth date.

My problem is so simple I guess but I haven't been able to find the solution...

When I have an empty date in MySQL (0000-00-00), my binded DateField indicates 1899-11-30

I tried almost everything possible... A custom labelFunction, a custom function called straight after the call to my service to try to handle my data like this.. :

```
protected function parseDate(date:Date):void
{
    if (date.getFullYear() == -1) {
        friendbirthdate.selectedDate = null;
    }   else {
        var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter;
        df.formatString = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
        friendbirthdate.selectedDate = date;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this works only partially. When I try to update this same form in the database I get disconnected. I'm missing something here and would greatly appreciate a tip or two :-)

THANKS!

Comment: Fill in this blank "I tried almost everything possible ____ " to do what?  What do you expect to happen when you get an empty date back?  Have you run in debug mode to view the data coming back from the server to your Flex app? What is the date value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you store NULL for unknown dates, as opposed to '0000-00-00'. NULL is a more accurate value in this case.

If you want to store it as NULL and display it as a different value you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(date_column,'0000-00-00') as formatted_date
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will help somebody but I had trouble to insert values from a form, containing a DateField. That Form has been generated through the Flash Builder *Generate Form* tool.

The problem is that the service generated by Flash Builder expect a Date Object, no matter what... If you submit the form without selecting a date in the DateField, the service call crashes.

Let's have a look at a part of the generated sample service (Create and Update functions), we can see that PHP is expecting to transform a Date Object to a String like this :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $item->friendname, $item->friendlastname,  $item->friendbirth->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

First of all, be sure that your Date field in MySQL has as NULL default value.

Then alter the create and update functions like this :

```
if ($item->friendbirth == null)
    $friendbirth = null;
else
    $friendbirth = $item->friendbirth->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $item->friendname, $item->friendnickname, $friendbirth);
```

This way, the service call script won't try to do kinda **null->toString('...')**